# Formatting floats using an f-string in a conditional statement while checking if the user input is an integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, f-string

I'm working on a program that

1. receives a positive integer as an input
2. multiplies the input by a certain number
3. returns the result so that it has 2-decimal places

This is how the program currently functions:

// Enter a positive integer...: 1

// [Expected Outcome] Result: 1.00

// [Actual Outcome] ValueError: Invalid format specifier

There seems to be a problem with the say I'm formatting the f-string when printing the result.
Could you please check what's wrong with the syntax?

```
rand_num = 1.0
value = int(input('Enter a positive integer...: '))
result = rand_num * value

print(f'Result: {result:.2f if value > 0 else "Why don't you check your input value again?"}')
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not put the `if/else` inside the `f-string`, just

```
print(f'Result: {result:.2f}' if value > 0 else "Why don't you check your input value again?")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can un-complicate your loop like this:

```
In [600]: if value > 0: 
     ...:     print(f'Result: {result:.2f}') 
     ...: else: 
     ...:     print("Why don't you check your input value again?") 
     ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Result: 1.00
```

Answer (score 0):

There is two problems with the 'f-string' part of your code:

- For nested expression, you need additional brackets
- You can't escape the quote character (in Why don't you check...) inside an f-string

I added the brackets and moved the message to a separate variable, now it works:

```
rand_num = 1.0
value = int(input('Enter a positive integer...: '))
result = rand_num * value

input_check_msg = 'Why don\'t you check your input value again?'    
print(f"Result: {result:{'.2f' if value > 0 else input_check_msg}}")
```